# How to show Arabic properly in PDF files?

Tags: pdf, language-support, arabic

I have some PDF files in Arabic, They work fine on windows. however not on **Ubuntu 12.04**. In **System Settings ▸**  **Language support** I did install **Arabic**. I also tried other **PDF** programs but I just get messed up letters.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your comment

> it says "cannot find or create the font 'SimplifiedArabic,Bold'..." any idea how to add that font or something ???

and Googling for [Simplified Arabic](https://www.google.com/search?q=SimplifiedArabic) shows up to you [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=261) on Microsoft website from where you can easily reach (and purchase for 36€) the font family you are missing.

Unfortunately for you, the pdf file your are trying to look does not embed its fonts, so you need to have them properly installed on your system from other sources.

If you have the possibility maybe it can be a good idea to ask to the producer of the pdf to give you a version with embedded fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Download this >> ftp://ftp.foolabs.com/pub/xpdf/xpdf-arabic.tar.gz

Then Copy/Paste this in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install xpdf-arabic
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the traditional Arabic font. [Download here](http://www.ahya.org/amm/modules.php?name=Downloads&d_op=getit&lid=40) and double click to install the font.

Answer (score 0):

(Moved my comment here, it may help someone & stop [Community ♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community) from poping it again)

To my experience, Seem your PDF needs Microsoft Fonts Set. Check used fonts from Menu: File → Properties → Fonts . Install them manually or most used ones using the command below. But note, Some font will not work even so, because they have a strict distribution license to be used only within Windows OS. It always shows scrambled symbols (like a hidden protection script embedded in the font).

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried opening them in **Adobe Reader**:

```
sudo apt-get install acroread
```

or click [this](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/acroread)[image: Install acroread]

Comment: yes I actually did, didn't help :( it says "cannot find or create the font 'SimplifiedArabic,Bold'..." any idea how to add that font or something ??? thanks !!